# How to access secret key from Azure vault

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I have followed the official document and developed the code, but it's not working. I have to get the secret key stored in the vault.

When I debug, it just stops at the mentioned step and doesn't go further. I also tried without debugging. It's the same. Are there any more settings/permissions to make.

```
private void EncryptFields()
{
  string publicKey = GetAzureVaultSecret().Result;
}

public static async Task<string> GetAzureVaultSecret() 
{
  var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAzureVaultAccessToken));
  var secret = await kv.GetSecretAsync(GlobalConstants.AzureVaultURLSecretURI);            
  return secret.Value;         
}

public static async Task<string> GetAzureVaultAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
  var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
  ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(GlobalConstants.AzureVaultClientId, GlobalConstants.AzureVaultClientSecret);

  //STOPS AT THE BELOW STEP AND NOTHING HAPPENS
  AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

   if (result == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the token");
    }

    return result.AccessToken;            
}
```

**Log:**

> ManagedPoolThread #3 00:23:46 WARN  Memory usage exceeded the
>   MemoryMonitor threshold. ManagedPoolThread #3 00:23:46 WARN  Memory
>   usage: 3,21,95,91,168 ManagedPoolThread #3 00:23:46 WARN  Number of
>   suppressed logs due to the minimum time between log entries: 10